# Error when saving an IP on a variable on alexa skills

Tags: python, http-post, alexa-skills-kit

I was trying to make alexa send a post request to a site located on my computer, but every time a put my computer ip in any string or variable the skill can't be called and return: A problem occurred with the requested Skill response.

Some additional information: i am using xampp for server the site; The skill is alexa hosted; My alexa is at the same network of my computer; I am using the requests library to make the post request; Every time i remove the ip and change for anything else the skill work normally.

The code of the skiłl:

```
class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
"""Handler for Skill Launch."""
def can_handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

    return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

def handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response

    myobj = {'pedido': 'teste', 'valor': 'teste'}
    
    try:
        x = requests.post("http://192.168.0.0/alexaajudaeu/Comando.php", data = myobj)
        print(x.text)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print('erro com o metodo post, \nerro: ' + str(e))

    speak_output = "Olá, bem vindo ao modo de assistência da sua alexa, como posso ajudar?"

    return (
        handler_input.response_builder
            .speak(speak_output)
            .ask(speak_output)
            .response
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**You're IP is a local IP** (it's within your router, that's not your IP on the outside world and your router needs to be configured to accept it)

Alexa is calling this URL from a server and therefore doesn't have access to your local IPs.

Use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) if you want to make your local server available from anywhere.

Comment: But i can't even run the command, the skill give an error when is called, but if i change the url to anything without the ip it run normally. I just trying to understand why it not run when the ip is there.
Note: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think you need to have a better understanding on network and IP. That's common knowledge and skipping a step to code directly is like driving without license. It work but you don't know know how.

Comment: I totally agree with you, i know i'm skipping some steps, and really wanna study network and servers, but i got i little bit confused when just the fact that i put my ip on a variable make the entire code can't run, i even put the variable inside a try.

Comment: The problem is the IP, it's a local one. Alexa or any server outside of your network will not understand it if it's not public.